# Form and Processing page on separate HTTPS domains. Any risks?

Tags: tls, web-application

If I have a form on a HTTPS site and my processing page (which is also HTTPS) is on a completely different domain, will the data be secure?

For example: `https://example.com` has a form with `action="https://processingpage.com"` is there any risk with the data that is sent from the form?

Can it be intercepted? Does it have to be encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

In the situation you described the data is transported securely and cannot be intercepted between the two domains.

However, it may be harder to implement something to prevent [cross site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing really wrong there, but as you change domain, you loose the notion of session which only makes sense on one single site. And you cannot prevent other sites to include a *copy* of your form (same fields) and post the result to your processing site with potentially unexpected values.

That being said, as both the form and the processing page are HTTPS, the exchange is as much secure as permitted by HTTPS. You can read [this other question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/51500/70738) if you want to know more on HTTPS limits.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify there would be no chance of the data being intercepted between the two domains?

Comment: @SamAllen:neither more nore less than in a single domain use case...